# Mac Calendar app on 10.13.6 High Sierra editing event descriptions

Tags: macos, calendar

Whenever I create a new event in my calendar and start typing a description, e.g. Hairddresser, a list of previously used descriptions appears.

This is useful but after a while I just want to delete those descriptions I no longer want to appear. How do I access the list where they are stored to delete them?

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I hope you come to find this site a useful resource. One thing I'd like to point out is that this site works best with only one question per question, so I've edited out the second question about a manual for the Calendar app. However, in case you haven't seen it, Apple has a [guide](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/calendar/welcome/mac) online that may be useful.